# How to use the boats as Batman in Free Roam Mode

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Basically, I have beaten the games' campaign, so I am in Free Roam/sandbox mode. As Batman, I try to go across that huge lake, yet can't because the two rafts are out of reach of my batclaw. How do I get across the lake, or can you get across at all after beating the main campaign?

Comment: Have you tried using the line launcher to get to another vantage point?  You should be able to find one of the platforms that is close enough to pull the raft to you.  I assume also you're talking about the Iceberg Lounge area.

Comment: Is this an option in the console versions or just the PC versions?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you're talking about the lake part in the Iceberg Lounge, to cross it you have two options:

- As mentioned in the comments, use the line launcher to travel across it.
- Toss a freeze grenade in the water and hop on it to create your own raft, you can then pull yourself with the batclaw.

Answer (score 1):

At least three, actually:

Grapple-boost wall-stall (jump, cling), as well as line-launcher and freeze-blast ice-floe raft.